# I want to convert best.pt weights file to tfjs - model.json and bin.wt file format

Tags: pytorch, tensorflow.js

I have trained my custom model and recieved the best.pt and last.pt weights. however, i want to convert these files to tensorflow - TFJS which consists of Model.json and bin.wt.
can you guys help me, how can i convert the file format please?